# redirect http to https via htaccess only for few pages

Tags: .htaccess, https

I have as SSL enabled website.

**Issue :** I want that http will redirect to https only for checkout pages.

I am using following code for redirection:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

but it redirects all http to htaccess.

**What I Want :** I want to put some condition on htaceess so that only checkout pages will redirect to https otherwise no redirection will be done.

Answer (score 0):

you have to catch the requests for your checkout pages coming on port 80

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} your-checkout-uri-pattern
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://your-sslized-site/$1 [R,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

The below piece of code solves my problem (when i was using it in api). It might also slove your problem. Give it a try.

Here you go,

```
# For redirecting HTTP to HTTPS, comments are line by line
# below line checks for https flag
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
# below line excludes the mentioned URIs from redirection
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(myFirstUri|mySecondUri|myThirdUri)
# below line redirects all other URIs except the ones that are mentioned above
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

So, whats happening here is that all my requests will be re-directed to https except the below ones

> abc.123/myFirstUri will become http://abc.123/myFirstUri
>
> abc.123/myFirstUri/qw/etc will also be re-directed as stated above

And the others requests will be re-directed to https e.g

> abc.123/test becomes https://abc.123/test